# Move contacts to folders

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

I'm trying to accomplish something that's apparently unusual: keep my contacts categorised.

I believe the tool I need are folders (rather than lists or groups) and I eventually learnt how to create them. However, I'm unable to move contacts to folders:

- You can't drag and drop contacts
- Folder contact menu does not have relevant entries
- Contacts don't have context menus
- There aren't relevant entries in toolbar
- You can't import contacts into a folder

[image: Screen-shot]

How are folders meant to be used? Do I need to create new contacts and re-type manually all the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to create new contacts and re-type manually all the data. There's no way to move existing contacts into a folder.

This was confirmed by a Microsoft Agent in [Microsoft Community Support](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/opeople-ocontacts/move-contact-to-folder/5525fef2-b490-4a09-bbed-ebb21551f6a4?tm=1534750398610).